# Error while using Karate with Junit

Tags: junit, karate

I have followed the steps from [this link][1].

The below error got fixed. But i am facing a new error now.I tried to resolve it but couldn't find a proper solution for it. Kindly help.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptions.getJunitOptions()Ljava/util/List;
  [1]: https://www.joecolantonio.com/2017/03/23/rest-test-tool-karate-api-testing/

New error:

    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: cucumber/runtime/junit/JUnitOptions
        at com.intuit.karate.junit4.Karate.<init>(Karate.java:38)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:29)
        at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:21)
        at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
        at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
        at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
        at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:26)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createUnfilteredTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:84)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:70)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:43)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:444)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: cucumber.runtime.junit.JUnitOptions
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 18 more
```

Answer (score -1):

Please create a fresh Eclipse workspace and try again.

Edit:

Sorry this error has not been reported before, so it must be some basic problem with your environment.

1. Try to upgrade or remove the Eclipse Cucumber Plugin
2. Try to run `mvn test` from the command line after installing Maven
3. Re-install or upgrade Eclipse
4. Try to clear your local Maven repository (try to search for info on how to do this)

Comment: Hi Peter, i have tried it in a new workspace too. But i am facing the same error

Comment: I tried the above mentioned things and now i am getting another error. i updated my question with the error